# Changing the frame of reference for a vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am doing a project and one of the things I need to do is to be able to change the frame of a vector field.

So, let us say we have a frame of reference, R. We have a vector field :
$$
\vec{F} = F_{x}(x, y, z) \hspace{1mm} \hat{x} + F_{y}(x, y, z) \hspace{1mm} \hat{y} + F_{z}(x, y, z) \hspace{1mm} \hat{z}
$$
which is being measured in the reference frame R - x, y and z being the coordinate variables.

Now, let us create a reference frame from R, say R', such that if we rotate R about z-axis by and angle $\alpha$, we get R'.

Now, my question is this:
If $X, Y, Z$ are the corresponding coordinate variables in the frame R', what is the vector field $\vec{F}$ as measured in R'?

Of course, my actual problem is of a more general nature - that is, to express $\vec{F}$ after any arbitrary rotation about all three axes - but this question will suffice as a way of explanation.

Also, I'd like to stress that I'm talking about vector fields - not free vectors (which is rather easy to handle for such a case) - and therefore just a transformation matrix isn't going to provide the correct answer.

Also, if the answer seems obvious to you, please by all means, point me in the right direction.

---

I have an idea of how this might work, though I'm not at all sure. So, what we can perhaps do is to replace x, y, z in $\vec{F}$ by functions of X, Y, Z and $\alpha$. Then, we can replace the base vectors with corresponding base vectors in the new frame - after the appropriate transformations of course. That should, I believe, give us the measure of $\vec{F}$ in R'. Again, I'm not sure about this.

I appreciate any help in this matter.

Comment: Your plans seems right to me. You need two rounds of transformations, one for coordinates and one for the vectors. I suggest doing the problem for a specific vector filed to make sure the transformations are the right ones.